# how to move the cursor to the end of the new line in content editable div on arrow down event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to move the cursor to the end of the new line in content editable div on  arrow down event. Now it is placing the cursor at the same point where the cursor was on previous line.

```html
    <div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="white-space:pre"> 1.how are you? 
    2. Where do u live ? 
    3. Salary ?</div>

<script>
$("#test").keydown(function (ev) {

    ev = ev || window.event;
    var evKey = (ev.which || ev.keyCode);

    if (evKey == 40 || evKey == 38)
 {
  ev.preventDefault();
    var element = document.getElementById("test");
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
               && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") 
  {
      var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
     var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
      var sel = win.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
       range.deleteContents();
      preCaretTextRange = range.cloneRange();
      preCaretTextRange.selectNodeContents(element);
      preCaretTextRange.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
       //without \g it will gointo infinite loop
        var re = /[\r\n]/g;
     var match, indexes= [];
     var i = 1;
     var TextAfterCursor = preCaretTextRange.toString();
     while (match= re.exec(TextAfterCursor))
    {
      indexes.push([i,match.index]);
      i++;
      }
      var index;
      
       if(indexes.length ==2)
       {
        index = indexes[1][1];
       }
      //if the indexes length is 1 then it will be the last line
      else if(indexes.length ==1)
       index = TextAfterCursor.length ;
       }
       var textNode = document.createTextNode(TextAfterCursor);
      range.insertNode(textNode);

      // Move the selection to the middle of the inserted text node
      range.setStart(textNode, index);
      range.setEnd(textNode, index);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }
   
 });
</script>
```

Here is the script that I come up with, it is setting the position to the end but it is appending the text after the initial cursor position second time.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet?

Comment: When pressing the  down arrow key that's what it's supposed to do. Try the 'end' key which is located in the upper right corner of a standard QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: @leigero I am struck at the step of getting the contents after the cursor position. WIndow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0) is always returning empty string even though cursor is placed at certain position in the div